# GetMethod returns null

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

Okay, so I have this class:

```
public class tUObject
{
    public const string strSelect = "SELECT Id, cName, Major FROM tUObject WHERE Id = ";

    //constructors and stuff...

    public virtual void FillElem(ref List<tUObject> l, DataSet ds)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And in `MainWindow()` I want to get to `FillElem()` using `GetMethod()`:

```
static List<tUObject> obj = new List<tUObject>();
static DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
//...
string strClass = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Class"].ToString(); //"tUObject"
Type t = Type.GetType("UniDB_WPF." + strClass);  //tUObject with the assembly name
Type tlist = obj.GetType();                      //list<tUObject>
Type tset = objDataSet.GetType();                //DataSet

//Getting strSelect from tUObject
string strAccessSelect = t.GetField("strSelect").GetRawConstantValue().ToString() + ((int)item.Tag).ToString();
//...
//Getting FillElem from tUObject
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("FillElem", BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { tlist, tset }, null);
```

The problem is, `GetMethod()` returns null, while `GetField()` works perfectly. `tlist` and `tset` are not null and return "List'1" and "DataSet" respectively. So why is it happening?

Comment: should that `tlist` argument maybe be a little different, seeing that the type of the first argument is NOT `List<tUObject>`, but `ref List<tUObject>`

Comment: Tried `tlist.MakeByRefType()`, nothing has changed.

Comment: That SHOULD have done the trick...

Comment: after you edited the question there is no `BindingFlags.Instance` included in the last line of code. Perhaps you should modify it to match Memoizer's suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Getting FillElem from tUObject
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("FillElem", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { tlist.MakeByRefType(), tset }, null);
```

Comment: This hasn't changed the situation, unfortunately.

Comment: For some reason your solution didn't work until I re-opened my project after making a quick `GetMethod()` example where it worked and pasted your code. I'll try to understand what happened and why it didn't work before. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Memoizer's answer should work.
The following code returns correct data:

```
public class Test
{
    public virtual void Test1(ref List<object> t1, object t2)
    {

    }
}
```

and method request

```
var t = new Test();
var mi = t.GetType().GetMethod("Test1", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { typeof(List<object>).MakeByRefType(), typeof(object) }, null);
```

[image]

So you need to search another problem. Are you sure that you are passing the correct types?

Comment: I made a quick `GetMethod()` example based on your code and it worked. Then I re-opened my project and copied the Memoizer's answer with `BindingFlags.Instance` and... it worked. I am quite baffled by all this. But thank you anyway.